# Why is NumberForm not good with ListPlot?

Tags: plotting, number-representation

Is NumberForm not good with the following use of ListPlot? Look at my example:

```
 vectorj = {Rationalize[0.3],NumberForm[1.2131, 2]};
 ListPlot[vectorj]
```

This is not working. Is 1.21 not recognized as a number because of NumberForm which just prints out? Could anybody tell me how to output an approximate value of 1.2131 as 1.21 and then use it in ListPlot correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In contrast to the numbers, such as 1.21 with the head Real, the `NumberForm` is not. Let us try with the heads

```
    1.2131 // Head
NumberForm[1.2131, 2] // Head

(*  Real

  NumberForm  *)
```

This is the reason.

Comment: may `N` work rather than `NumberForm`?